# Eclipse Oxygen Upgrade - "Java Virtual Machine Launcher - A Java Exception has occured)"

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I upgraded from Neon to Oxygen and now many of my projects with Ant builds get the error

"Java Virtual Machine Launcher - A Java Exception has occurred"

First, my situation is NOT the same as [18453100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453100/ant-not-working-in-eclipse-kepler-java-virtual-machine-launcher-a-java-except).  I reset the Ant classpath defaults to no effect.  And deleting all the metadata caused Ant builds in all projects to fail.

I have found that copying an ant build.xml in a project that works to a similar project where builds did not work caused the Ant build to now get the JVM error.

What I did discover that in Run Configuration - Classpath - Additional Tasks & Support, Ant tasks in projects that work have about 20 entries, whereas when that same file is copied to a new project then there are only 5 entries.  And going back to Neon, all those run configurations have the same 5 entries. And BTW the Ant Home classpath entries are the same (Default) in all projects.

Classpath in Neon and non-working Oxygen projects
[image]

Classpath in Oxygen working projects
[image]

So I'm thinking that the upgrade to oxygen did not add those extra 15 references to the classpath for some projects.  But I cannot find anything in the project properties to correct that.  Doing it one by one for over a dozen projects is not what I had in mind.

Would anyone know how to reset those?  Or any other way?

Answer (score 2):

**for me below worked (eclipse oxygen and I wanted to compile with 1.7):**

windows-preferences-Ant Runtime-
-under Ant Home Entries remove all eclipse jar and include all ant libraries 
-under global entries (point it to tools.jar of 1.7)
-build.xml-> external tools configuration-->remove your existing build.xml-->and under JRE tab - "Separate JRE"-->point it to your JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Install lower version of Ant (for example 1.9.x for jdk 7) and set this ant directory as ant home in "Window > Preferences > Ant > Runtime: Classpath tab"